# Scientist E-mail

Tags: riddle, cipher, steganography

> FROM : Prof. Heart Laft (heartlaft@puzzling.se)
> TO : Dr. Spy Acornic (spyacornic@puzzling.se)
>
> SUBJECT : TRUTH
>
> 119101039114101 098101105110103 099104097115101100 098121 103111118101114110109101110116
>
> attachment : 
> [image: steghide]
> [image: loc.jpg]

---

> There are 3 hidden messages.

<sub>*This is my first puzzle. I appreciate any feedback to make it better. Hope you like it.*</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok so :

> The 1st secret message is an ascii-encoded string that can be decoded to "we'rebeingchasedbygovernment". [See this decoder](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/)

Then

> The 2nd message is the text in the image decoded in base64. It is RVhQT1JUVEhJUOINQUdFVE9DQUVTQVIuVFhUVOIUSFBBU1NQSFJBUOVDQUVTQVI= which  reads: EXPORTTHISIMAGETOCAESAR.TXTWITHPASSPHRASECAESAR. When decrypted with the UNIX tool `steghide` and the passphrase CAESAR we find the following hexadecimal sequence:  `56 55 4e 49 52 53 42 48 41 51 4e 50 45 4e 50 58 42 41 47 55 52 53 56 45 5a 4e 5a 52 41 47` which translate to VUNIRSBHAQNPENPXBAGURSVEZNZRAG. Using the famous Caesar Cipher we found that it translates to: `IHAVEFOUNDACRACKONTHEFIRMAMENT` when applying a ROT13.

Finally:

> -4f +a1 may correspond to hexadecimal modification, because they are both correct hexadecimal number. One should delete every 4f and replace them with a1 in the PNG. I did this, but it resulted in nothing (no additional data appears). Maybe is it just lat/long coordinates (the title of the image is loc.jpg) in hexadecimal. This gives us [this position on google maps](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/79%C2%B000'00.0%22S+161%C2%B000'00.0%22E/@-78.6455442,157.5339599,6.5z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d-79!4d161)

Comment: Almost there. 1 left. I think you're too complicated at last message.

Comment: I updated my last answer, can you check ?

Comment: Can you give me a feedback for better puzzle

Comment: That was great, but I personally prefer when the are linked together, like answer 1 gives you a hint for answer 2 etc. e.g: your second hint could have add the word "at" at the end of the sentence so we know the next answer is probably a location. It gives the reader a sense of accomplishment and help for the context and clarity.

Answer (score 9):

The second phrase is a base64 text which says:

> EXPORTTHISIMAGETOCAESAR.TXTWITHPASSPHRASECAESAR

The two scientists names are anagrams:

> Heart Laft = Flat Earth
>  Spy Acornic = conspiracy

Furthermore:

> The names of the two images are as follow:
>  steghide.jpg  - it implies it has to do with steganography
>  loc.jpg - possible some sort of coordinates (location)

Based on the findings of @betcheg about the second phrase and the assumption that we are talking indeed about:

> Location

in the 2nd image. So using the second phrase:

> I think the hidden 3rd message is more like a joke - if you look at the map location of the coordinates, they point just at the beginning of the Transantarctic mountains. The flat-earthers believe that the firmament could be reached if you cross Antarctica so on the map we can visually see that this firmament has started to crack, just like the message says.

Comment: Sorry but Scientist name doesn't include in hidden messages. It's just for joke. Anyway, you have found it. +1

Comment: @nathoenk I guess as much, as I haven't yet figured what the second image hides.

Comment: As note that you have not complete solved the first image yet.

Comment: @nathoenk What do you think of my far-fetched logic about the 3rd message?

Comment: I appreciate your answer. The timeline here says that betcheg answer first. But I love your logic.

Answer (score 5):

first hidden message is:

> we'rebeingchasedbygovernment 
> the numbers are just ASCII

Comment: 2 left. Do you think it's too easy? I'll be more carefull next time.